# ASP.NET Margin issue in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, html, css, google-chrome

I've got a fairly simple design that I'm working on in ASP.NET.

The problem is when I take the design from flat HTML which works fine, to asp.net, it adds what looks to be a 20px blank margin at the top of the page and around certain elements.

I presumed this was to do with the not having set my margins to 0px on the body and form elements in the CSS. I've done this, and it still has the problem in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE7 or IE8.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us some relative sample, maybe as Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some unwanted margins on ASP.NET pages and they had something to do with invalid markup (might have been because of a missing div end tag or something similar - I can't remember the exact reason). So check your markup. Also make sure that you are using a valid doctype (i.e. not in quirks rendering mode).

[Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) is often a great help in this kind of situations. You can inspect exactly which element is causing the extra margins. Chrome has a similar "Inspect element" functionality built in.

Comment: Oh wow, that's pretty bad on my behalf! Interesting one for future reference though - I tried it in Firebug instead of the Chrome Google Toolbar and it turns out the Cufon javascript I had in the page was adding padding on certain elements. I just had to add cufon, cufon-canvas = margin: 0px and it fixed it!

But your answer pointed me in the right direction! Stupid Cufon!

Thanks!